# Why process substitution with binary doesn't work?

Tags: bash, redirect

```
feh <(cat img.jpg);
```

The above command doesn't work with the error `feh: No loadable images specified.`.

`cat img.jpg | feh -;`
`feh < <(cat img.jpg);`

The above commands work fine.

`echo <(cat img.jpg);` simply shows `/dev/fd/63`. I don't know why `feh` doesn't open `/dev/fd/63`. Plz help.

Comment: But `mpv <(cat img.jpg)` works fine... ???

Comment: DUPLICATION of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181932/process-substitution-for-opening-a-list-of-files-with-an-application

Comment: What is wrong with `feh img.jpg`?? Why do you want any type of substitution here?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In case of `feh <(unzip -p zip.zip img.jpg)`, it's useful.

Comment: That explains it. Without the example it was a bit bewildering what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it correctly, but `feh` has a bug/feature that makes it fail.

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/derf/feh/blob/7d154c00258c70136b0bca8ae162fe08c645373e/src/filelist.c#L241), you can see how this happened. In pseudo-code with a lot of details excluded, it goes like this:

```
void add_file_to_filelist_recursively(path, is_first_level) {
  if (is_first_level) {
    if(path_is_url(path)) {
      // Download
    } else if(path == "-") {
      // Read STDIN
    }
  }

  if(is_directory(path)) {
    for(file in path) {
      add_file_to_filelist_recursively(file, false);
    }
  } else if(is_regular_file(path)) {
    add(path);
  }
}
```

It's a simple function for recursively looking for files, and it also handles URLs and `-` specially when directly specified on the command line (and not when they appear as filenames)

While recursing, it will add regular files, and it will descend into directories. Anything else will be skipped. This is presumably because it rarely makes sense to try to read sockets, devices and fifos. However, as a side effect, it will also ignore your `/dev/fd/63` since it's a fifo.

One might argue that `feh` should try to read whatever the user explicitly specifies, and that would be a simple fix. However, as it is, there's no way to make it work with Bash's process substitution directly.

Comment: Not only `feh` but also `eog` and `gimp` don't work. 
Does it mean that they all share the same file reading algorithm??

Comment: Due to the way process substitution works, it's easy to break support. Some programs close all unknown FDs (like 63) on startup, some are client/server or single instance where the executable just relays commands but not open FDs, and some try to open files twice or rewind them which fifos don't support. You'd have to look at each individual program to see the particular reason why it fails.